# How to access array fields in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass two arrays ($a_1 and $a_2) from my controller to my view like so:

```
$this->load->view('confirm_data_v', $a_1, $a_2);
```

In my view I want to print the value of one of them doing this:

```
<p><?php echo $name ?></p>
<p><?php echo $mail ?></p>
```

when I print each array I get this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => jon
)
Array
(
    [mail] => blabla@server.com

)
```

$name is a field inside $a_1 and $mail is a field inside $a_2, but it seems like the view doesn't know where these fields are, I mean, it doesn't know in wich array is $name and $mail, wether $a_1 or $a_2. How do I do that?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the arrays in an incorrect way. You can only pass one data array as a second parameter while loading the view.

You could instead put each array in the data array in your controller:

```
$data['a_1'] = $a_1;
$data['a_2'] = $a_2;
$this->load->view('confirm_data_v', $data);
```

Then in your view you can access $a_1 and $a_2 as you like

```
Name: <?php echo $a_1['name']; ?>
Email: <?php echo $a_2['mail']; ?>
```

Comment: And then, how do I print them in the view? <p><?php echo $a_1->name?></p>

Answer (score 1):

the codeigniter wiki sais this

```
$data = array(
               'name' => $a_1['name'],
               'mail' => $a_2['mail'],
          );

$this->load->view('confirm_data_v', $data);
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: And then, how do I print them in the view? <p><?php echo $a_1->name?></p>